# Use a string instead of a file in this curl post command

Tags: curl

This request works fine on my Linux:

```
curl -F out=json -F "content=<FILE.html" http://validator.w3.org/nu/
```

Now I want to modify this curl command and use a string instead of a file.
The raw html does not work because this sign "<" is interpreted as redirection by curl and also the sign "!" from

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

is interpreted by the shell.

I tried to use backslashes but it gets sent to the service endpoint too which does not help either.

Here is the content of FILE.html that I want to send as a string:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title></title></head><body></body></html>
```

Comment: It might become relevant which OS you do this on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`--form-string`](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#--form-string) instead of -F to make the string literal (ie not parse the less than sign) and just quote the string with single quotes to make the bang lose its meaning to the shell;

```
curl -F out=json \
   --form-string 'content=<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title></title></head><body></body></html>' \
   http://validator.w3.org/nu/
```